# Power Shell Script for loop?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to create a script in PowerShell to run a utility with some default parameters. There will be multiple IP addresses into a CSV file that we will need to import. Then do a loop to run the utility for each IP address imported.

```
Set-Location 'C:\Program Files\Utility
$printerlist = Get-Content ".\Printer.csv"
$pass = Read-Host "Enter your Password"

.\Utility.exe -USERNAME="ADMIN" -PASSWORD="$pass"-ADDRESS="$printerlist" -PP-INSTALL="192.168.33.21" -JA-INSTALL="192.168.33.21" -IPA-INSTALL="192.168.33.21" -QUOTA-DELETE 

Foreach($printer in $printerlist){
   echo $line

}
```

Comment: Why not move your `.\Utility.exe` line into the foreach loop and set `-ADDRESS=$printer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment points out, you need to loop over those IP addresses.  You can use a feature called splatting to apply a set of default arguments:

```
Set-Location -Path $Env:ProgramFiles\Utility

$pass = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter your Password'
$utilArgs = @(
    '-USERNAME="ADMIN"'
    "-PASSWORD=""$pass"""
    '-PP-INSTALL="192.168.33.21"'
    '-JA-INSTALL="192.168.33.21"'
    '-IPA-INSTALL="192.168.33.21"'
    '-QUOTA-DELETE'
)

foreach ($printer in Get-Content -Path Printer.csv) {
    .\Utility.exe "-ADDRESS=""$printer""" @utilArgs
}
```

---

## Docs

### [`about_Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ran the script you provided but it's reading multiple IP addresses versus a single $printer address which is producing an "Ip address could not be reached" message.

Comment: Without insight to what's inside your file, there's no way I can help you past that.  Add a sample to your question with the headers if there are any.